# How does correct grammar affect password security?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, passphrase

When using the [XKCD password methodology](https://xkcd.com/936/), entropy is calculated solely on the basis of individual words, assuming that the individual words are independent. This is, of course, not necessarily a valid assumption, unless you specifically ensure it when you generate passwords; and a password made of four random and independent words is still harder to remember than a grammatically correct phrase. [zxcvbn](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html) similarly reports entropy based only on the individual words found, without apparently carrying out any calculation of relative frequency.

Presumably, with a sufficiently large N-gram database, you could generate a reasonably sophisticated statistical model of the word usages of correct English and order password guesses of the XKCD form accordingly. So, the question: how much entropy is lost if using a memorable, grammatical phrase for a password, by comparison to the same number of words independently selected? How much longer must a grammatical password be to provide equivalent entropy/security? Are password crackers actually using this method?

Comment: You may find [this paper](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/myl/Shannon1950.pdf) interesting - in fact, it might answer part of your question.

Comment: Quite often words like 'Passsw0rd' or "P4ssword" appear in dictionaries, and hence are easily crackable..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, any information which can narrow the search space for a password will
reduce the strength of that password. So, in theory, it would make sense to assume
that grammatically correct passwords are potentially weaker than those which are a
collection of unrelated words or have deliberate grammatical errors. However,
calculating exactly what the differences would be is extremely hard.

Many password cracking programs will allow you to define complex patterns. For
example, it has been observed that people often use dates as a way of including
numbers in a password i.e. password1961 or even password171067 (or password101767 for
US date), so some password crackers will search for things like
[dictonary-word][year] and [dictionary-word][date], where the numbers in the
year/date will be restricted to digits which would be valid and within an 'expected'
range (i.e. assume year/date is related to current/recent period or users date of
birth etc). Likewise, studies of passwords indicate people tend to do things like put
'special' characters at the boarders of password components i.e. password:1972. This
might suggest it would be a good idea to not use digits of this format and consider
using 3, 5, 7 digit numbers rather than 4 or 6 and if you add special/punctuation
characters, do so in /unusual/ positions i.e. pas:sword1972 (and of course, don't use
'password' :-(

As a cracker, the challenge of using grammar would be in how to model it. For
example, English has a very complex grammar. This is partially why natural language
processing is such a challenge. Theoretically, if you could define the grammar with
sufficient accuracy and had a large enough dictionary, you could generate a system
which could produce a dictionary of /valid/ sentences. However, this would still
represent a very large search space. If you know exactly how many characters are in the password, this would help reduce the search space, but it would be very
large. What would need to be determined is how much smaller such a dictionary would
be compared to a similar dictionary just consisting of random words concatenated
together. It would be smaller, but whether it would be sufficiently smaller to make
any practical difference is unknown. If the grammar based dictionary meant an average
search time of 50 years and the random word dictionary represented an average search
time of 500 years, in reality, neither approach are going to be useful (assuming
there are no other optimization which could reduce the time to a level which would be
practical).

Rather than a grammar based dictionary, I would probably compile a dictionary based
on quotes, well-known poetry and song lyrics. My theory is that when people use a
phrase as a password, that phrase will be something which is easy to remember and
therefore likely based on a song, poem or favourite quote. This would be an even
smaller dictionary. The challenge would be in building the database and ensuring it
is sufficiently comprehensive. Probably something which is getting easier given all
the digital repositories of quotes, songs, poetry etc out there.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about this too much. Obviously, it would be best not to
use well know phrases and it would be quite important to not use a phrase which
someone might be able to identify via social engineering techniques. If your a
military person, don't use famous military quotes/speeches, if you're a Christian,
avoid using quotes from the Bible, if your an obsessive fan of some
singer/actor/whatever, avoid using quotes from that person. Essentially, avoid using
anything which anyone who does some research on you might be able to use to narrow
the search space. I would also suggest using as long a phrase as possible. A very
long known quote is probably stronger than a shorter set of random words simply
because the search space is larger.

If you can remember a random set of words, then do that. However, if you can't, then
use a grammatically correct phrase, but make it as long as possible. Remembering the
password is probably as critical has ensuring it is strong. I've frequently found the
weakest part of many systems is their password recovery process and think you should
do as much as you can to avoid ever needing to use such a process. Enter the phrase
in reverse order (or some other pattern you can remember), insert special characters
and numbers into the words, not between them and avoid number patterns such as 2, 4
and 6 digits and stay away from quotes/phrases which someone could associate with
you.

Comment: You won't be able to find an obscure enough quote or song lyric for a secure password. Crackers can make a database of over a billion such phrases relatively quickly (a few hours) and crack any password using such a quote in minutes: http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/10/how-the-bible-and-youtube-are-fueling-the-next-frontier-of-password-cracking/. It will need to be an original phrase or it will fall to *untargeted* attacks.

Comment: @Ben We have to accept that passwords are fundamentally broken as a concept. The best we can do is hope we stay just in front of the current techniques and where possible, use things like 2FA. However, I think your statement that you can apply the technique in a few hours is for now overstated. As the article you cite points out, generating effective phrase lists is complex and time consuming and often requires using social eng. techniques to reduce the search space. This will change as pre-compiled phrase lists become more readily available, but for now it is a reasonable technique

Answer (score 5):

The research paper [Effect of Grammar on Security of Long Passwords](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2435395) answers your question. The following is the abstract from the paper.

Use of long sentence-like or phrase-like passwords such as "abiggerbetterpassword" and "thecommunistfairy" is increasing. In this paper, we study the role of grammatical structures underlying such passwords in diminishing the security of passwords. We show that the results of the study have direct bearing on the design of secure password policies, and on password crackers used for enforcing password security. Using an analytical model based on Parts-of-Speech tagging we show that the decrease in search space due to the presence of grammatical structures can be more than 50%. A significant result of our work is that the strength of long passwords does not increase uniformly with length. We show that using a better dictionary e.g. Google Web Corpus, we can crack more long passwords than previously shown (20.5% vs. 6%). We develop a proof-of-concept grammar-aware cracking algorithm to improve the cracking efficiency of long passwords. In a performance evaluation on a long password dataset, 10% of the total dataset was exclusively cracked by our algorithm and not by state-of-the-art password crackers.

Answer (score 4):

First of all: if you're selecting words non-randomly (to follow grammar rules, for example), then *this isn't an XKCD-style password at all*. From my understanding, "XKCD-style" just means [diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) with a smaller word list.

One problem with grammatically-correct sentences is, that unless they are meaningless nonsense, they're probably quite predictable. I don't know exactly how predictable, but I do know that [basically anything in print anywhere is insecure as the basis for a password](http://arstechnica.com/security/2013/10/how-the-bible-and-youtube-are-fueling-the-next-frontier-of-password-cracking/). So, you'll need to somehow generate a unique phrase that nobody will have uttered before.

That said, you should still be able to make a secure passphrase that (loosely) follows grammar rules by making randomized nonsense phrases like a Mad-Lib. Just do diceware using a different wordlist for each word. For example, your passphrase generator could generate passwords in the form:

```
{article} {adjective} {noun} {adverb} {verb} {article} {adjective} {noun}, {exclamation}{punctuation}
```

For example, "The stylish aardvark stupidly flings a lumpy blimp, yikes!"

I think a "sentence" like that would be much easier to remember than 6 completely random words all jumbled together, but obviously your total word list must be larger to achieve similar security.

You could have a list of 4096 each of nouns, adverbs, verbs, and adjectives (i.e. 16384 words total). We'll make it simple and say you have 2 punctuation marks (. or !) and 32 common exclamations ("oh my", "uh-oh", "rats", etc.). So you can calculate the entropy as:

```
1 + 12 + 12 + 12 + 12 + 1 + 12 + 12 + 5 + 1 = 80
```

Note that it's the size of the word lists for each word position that fully determines the entropy. The attacker could know exactly how you generate your password, and unless you're really unlucky and you manage to generate a common song lyric, you can still predict just how secure the password is just like the XKCD-style rule.

The key is that each word must be truly random, and either each word list must be large or you must make very long phrases.

It's probably easier to get large word lists that don't break down words by part of speech, and it's easier to distribute ONE word list and one easily understood rule, but the math should be exactly the same.

Disclaimer: I'm not a security expert, but I *think* I understand the math and the concepts involved here.

Comment: Hmm. This seems the answer to a separate question to what I was thinking of, which is meaningful (but long) English sentences. It does seem useful, however, and could cut down on the length requirement a bit, perhaps using some kind of random syntactically-valid-sentence generator.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood then. I'll update my answer a little bit.